# How to hide things like scroll indicators in UICollectionView of tvOS

Tags: ios, swift, tvos

Scrolling UICollectionView of tvOS will show something like scroll indicators. 
I want to hide it. What should I do now?

[image]

I tried showsVerticalScrollIndicator but it didn't work.

```
collectionView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
```

Comment: where you called this

Comment: try this self. collectionView.mask = nil

Comment: Thank you for your reply! “self. collectionView.mask = nil” didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set your scroll view

```
indexDisplayMode` to `UIScrollViewIndexDisplayModeAlwaysHidden
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I was able to hide the indicator.